# Sort an array of date ranges into groups where each group has no overlapping ranges (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, sorting, date-range, overlapping

I have an Array of objects & each object has a 'start' date & an 'end' date.

```
sortedDateRanges = [
    {
    id: 1,
    start: "2018-01-01",
    end: "2018-01-05",
    name: "First item"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    start: "2018-01-02",
    end: "2018-01-08",
    name: "Second item"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    start: "2018-01-06",
    end: "2018-01-13",
    name: "Third item"
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    start: "2018-01-14",
    end: "2018-01-14",
    name: "Fourth item"
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    start: "2018-02-01",
    end: "2018-02-15",
    name: "Fifth item"
  },
]
```

I need to sort these objects into groups where each group has NO overlapping date ranges. There are definitely multiple valid outputs. `[[{id: 1},{id: 3},{id: 4}], [{id: 2},{id: 5}]]` or `[[{id: 1}, {id: 3}, {id: 5}], [{id: 2}, {id: 4}]]` etc.

My current solution is just comparing each range to the previous range which doesn't produce an *incorrect* solution...it's just not a comprehensive solution like I am looking for. My current solution returns `[[{id: 1}],[{id: 2}],[{id: 3}, {id: 4}, {id: 5}]]`

```
export const groupUnoverlappedItems = sortedDateRanges => {
    let groups = [];
    let rangeIds = [];

    sortedDateRanges.map((current, idx, arr) => {
        if (idx === 0) {
            groups.push([current]);
            rangeIds.push(current.id);
            // return result;
        } else {
            let previous = arr[idx -1];

            // check for overlap
            let previousEnd = (new Date(previous.end)).getTime();
            let currentStart = (new Date(current.start)).getTime();
            let overlap = (previousEnd >= currentStart);

            if (overlap) {
                // if overlap, push new group
                groups.push([current]);
                rangeIds.push(current.id);
            } else if (rangeIds.indexOf(current.id) === -1) {
                groups[groups.length -1].push(current);
                rangeIds.push(current.id);
            }
        }
    });

    return groups;
};
```

Comment: Given the results you posted as a valid answer, I'd say your solution (if that's how you generated such) *is* wrong. The first three date ranges all overlap

Comment: Yes, obviously, I would not be posting this question if I had the solution I need.

I gave 2 _**examples**_ of valid answers. There are a lot of valid answers in this situation. I am looking to get help creating a method that will produce a solution that is more along the lines of the 2 examples I gave. @ControlAltDel

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand if you have a rule to define the groups, or they must be formed dinamically.

Anyway, why don't you get the object with the earliest start date, and use it to create the first object, in the first group.

You have a starting point, then you can find the object with the nearest start date, that doesn't overlap your first object end date. If you proceed sequentially, once you find a date that overlaps, you can be almost safe that is the good one to form the next group.

Once you don't find any other candidates for the first group, then you can check if another group exist (and has at least an object in it), then repeat the process, until all objects are allocated.

May I suggest to use a library, like [date-fns](https://date-fns.org/v2.9.0/docs/Interval), that helps you with useful methods to manipulate dates, and also define date intervals. Javascript has basic support for dates, using a library can save you a lot of time ;)

Comment: This is definitely helpful, thanks. I can try this approach. 

I am trying to accomplish this without using any external libraries.

Comment: Ok, so you can create a two Date objects  (dateStart, dateEnd),  the "next object" will be after the first, if ```dateStart2 > dateEnd1```, or before if ```dateStart2 < dateStart1```. I read that using major and minor sign is allowed with Date objects.
To create a date object: ``` var dateStartX = new Date(dateStartString);```  the string must be in the YYYY-mm-dd format, by default, but you can parse other formats, reading the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) may help.

Comment: My code above works for comparing & determining whether 2 given date ranges overlap. The part that I am struggling with is efficiently looping (& nested looping) without causing runtime errors or infinite loops...especially if the input array were something much longer.

¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: I think that [this article](https://www.sitepoint.com/sort-an-array-of-objects-in-javascript/) can help you. Array.sort() is an interesting function in your case, but first is important to split the objects in groups, avoiding overlapping. I think that is possible to do that check in the sort function as well! That would be super neat in my opinion :)

Comment: Okay, I see what you're saying. Cool.

Currently, I'm sorting the ranges before passing them into the function above. I sorted them by doing


```const sortDateRanges = timeLineItems => {
    return timeLineItems.sort((previous, current) => {
      let previousTime = previous.start;
      let currentTime = current.start;

      if (previousTime < currentTime) return -1;
      if (previousTime === currentTime) return 0;

      return 1;
    });
};
```

_BUT_ perhaps, I can make this sort function do a little bit more! Thanks for the direction!!

Comment: Yeah mate, you have to convert strings into Date objects. Now you are just asking if string A is major or minor of string B. I would also be more explicit with that logic, replacing the ```(previousTime === currenTime) return 0;``` with ```(previousTime > currenTime) return 1;```. Then if you want you can define when the function must return ```0```, but the sorting algorithm needs to know when an item goes before or after the current under evaluation, so < & > conditions should suffice to the task. It will be also clearer to read in the future! :-) good luck!